# nom parser borrow checker issue

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, nom

I have this Rust program using nom 4.2.2. (I have taken the liberty of expanding the nom parser function.)

```
extern crate failure;
extern crate nom;

use failure::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn nom_parser(i: &[u8]) -> ::nom::IResult<&[u8], String, u32> {
    { ::nom::lib::std::result::Result::Ok((i, ("foo".to_owned()))) }
}

fn my_parser(buf: &[u8]) -> Result<(&[u8], String), Error> {
  Ok((buf, "foo".to_owned()))
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
  let handler = |mut entries: String| { entries.clear() };
  loop {
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    File::open("/etc/hosts")?.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
    let res = nom_parser(&buf)?.1;
    // let res = my_parser(&buf)?.1;
    handler(res);
  }
}
```

Compiling this program with `rustc 1.33.0 (2aa4c46cf 2019-02-28)` yields the following issue:

```
error[E0597]: `buf` does not live long enough
  --> nom-parsing/src/main.rs:21:26
   |
21 |     let res = nom_parser(&buf)?.1;
   |               -----------^^^^-
   |               |          |
   |               |          borrowed value does not live long enough
   |               argument requires that `buf` is borrowed for `'static`
...
24 |   }
   |   - `buf` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Switching to the commented out version of the parser compiles just fine.  How are `my_parser` and `nom_parser` different? Who is borrowing buf? How should I change the program to placate the borrow checker?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let res = nom_parser(&buf)?.1;
                          ^ here
```

You are using the `?` operator to propagate the error out of `main`. The `IResult<&[u8], String, u32>` = `Result<(&[u8], String), nom::Err<&[u8], u32>>`. So in case of error the `&buf` is returned as part of it, so it must stay alive even after `main` function exits, but it won't because `buf` is local variable inside `main`.

In your case the `nom_parser` never returns error, but the validation only cares about the types and function signatures.

To fix it, you should process the error somehow before propagating it up. For example:

```
let res = nom_parser(&buf).map_err(|_| failure::format_err!("Parsing failed!"))?.1;
```

Note that `Err` in the `IResult` is not always *hard error*. It could be `nom::Err::Incomplete`, meaning that the parsing may succeed if more data is supplied, or `nom::Err::Error` meaning that the input was not matched by the parser (so perhaps another parser in `alt!` could succeed), or `nom::Err::Failure`, meaning that something went really wrong during parsing. Depending on the situation, you may consider them all as failure, or handle them differently.

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed seem to be the case! Simply mapping the error into a new error with the old error as a string did the trick. The real code uses `CompleteStr` so it should not have a "problem" with incomplete data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in `IResult<I, O, E = u32>`, which expends to `Result<(I, O), Err<I, E>>`

As you can see, when you use the `?`, the `Err` that you may return can still contain a reference to the type I, which is your `&[u8]`, and return from your function.

The only way for the function to return this reference would be that the reference has a lifetime that doesn't end with the function, `'static`

A simple solution to your problem would be to change the `&[u8]` to a `Vec<u8>`, even if I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it.